# Sql query OR function to reverse the Arabic strings

Tags: sql, oracle

I need sql query which will reverse the Arabic string.

Ex:

1. String 1: ABC DEF (Assume ABC DEF as Arabic string ) then out put should be CBA FED.
2. String 2: ABCDEF (Assume ABCDEF as Arabic string ) then out put should be FEDCBA.

Thanks
Rajeev Naik

Comment: will there be more than 1 space. ie , something like ABC DEF EFG

Comment: Yes There can be more than 1 spaces or it can contain the numerical numbers also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a 3 step process

1. split the string to rows using space as separator
2. reverse each string
3. join the strings back together

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10709/11)**

```
WITH spaceSplit as (
    SELECT 
        t.id,
        trim(regexp_substr(t.text, '[^ ]+', 1, lines.column_value)) text, 
        lines.column_value as seq
    FROM t,
      TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
      (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual
              CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(t.text, ' ')+1
      ) AS sys.odciNumberList ) ) lines
    ORDER BY id, lines.column_value
),
reverseString as (
    SELECT ID, REVERSE(text) as text, seq
    FROM spaceSplit
)
SELECT id, LISTAGG(text, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY seq) AS text
FROM   reverseString
GROUP BY id
;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID |     TEXT |
|----|----------|
|  1 |  CBA FED |
|  2 |   FEDCBA |
|  3 | BA DC FE |
```

Comment: Thanks Juan....It is adding junk characters in the Arabic characters. Actual Arabic character is:   رقائق بطاطس جبن و بصل مرامي

Comment: then outputted string coming as :�٦ا؂ٱ �طاطب �٨ج � �ٵب �م٧ر؅

Comment: Well I cant help you much there the arabic characters looks like junk to me. Can you try using another special char as sapartor instead of space? try `,` coma or `.` dot or `|` pipe. or maybe an not common arabic char. What step you get the weird char 1, 2 or 3?